# Update Variable based on Group

Tags: t-sql, variables, sql-update

I need to perform an update to a field in a table with a variable, but I need the variable to change when the group changes. It is just an INTt, so for example if I The example below I want to update the record of texas with a 1 and flordia with the next number of 2:

UPDATE table 
set StateNum = @Count
FROM table
where xxxxx
GROUP BY state

Group         Update Variable
Texas         1
Texas         1
Florida       2
Florida       2
Florida       2

Comment: Or is there a default variable that I can use on a group change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use a lookup table with the state and its number `StateNum` Then you should store this number instead of the name to your table.

You might use `DENSE_RANK` within an updateable CTE:

--mockup data

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE([state] VARCHAR(100),StateNum INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl([state]) VALUES
('Texas'),('Florida'),('Texas'),('Nevada');
```

--your update-statement

```
WITH updateableCTE AS
(
    SELECT StateNum
          ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY [state]) AS NewValue
    FROM @tbl 
)
UPDATE updateableCTE SET StateNum=NewValue;
```

--check the result

```
SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

And then you should use this to get the data for your lookup table

```
SELECT StateNum,[state] FROM @tbl GROUP BY StateNum,[state];
```

Then drop the state-column from your original table and let the StateNum be a foreign key.